# Howe to install a Plugin for Jekyll with a homebrew install of ruby running on local Mac?

Tags: ruby, jekyll, jekyll-extensions

I am running latest MAC OSX with `brew`. I have installed `Ruby` with `brew install ruby` and have successfully installed Jekyll as per instructions. `sudo gem install jekyll`.

I am unable to get `_plugins` working and get errors when i try to do install the seo plugin. `gem 'jekyll-seo-tag'`

I get `Unknown command jekyll-seo-tag`

How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 2):

Where are you adding `gem 'jekyll-seo-tag'` to? Based on the error, I guess you're trying to run it as a command:

```
$ gem 'jekyll-seo-tag'
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError)
    Unknown command jekyll-seo-tag
```

You should add `gem 'jekyll-seo-tag` to your `Gemfile` instead:

```
$ cat Gemfile
source 'https://rubygems.org/'
...
gem 'jekyll-seo-tag'
...
```

And then to your `_config.yml` file:

```
$ cat _config.yml
...
gems:
  - jekyll-seo-tag
...
```

For more information, take a look at the installation instructions:

https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll-seo-tag#installation

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I found the whole `_plugin` overkill so ended up extending the header `_include` with liquid Metadata for search, social.